# .NET: deployment SQL connection string

Tags: sql, .net, deployment, configuration, connection-string

I've got a .NET project that I have to deploy on different machines with different enviroments.

Some machines use internal network addresses to access the DB others have to do it over public internet IPs.

What are the best practices to configure SQL connection strings in the web.config for such a task?

Answer (score 0):

you may have a setting form in your project witch can be accessed by user before any activity with DB. Probably in the project's login section (if the project has any!). In that form you can ask user to input appropriate DB setting (IP,UserID and Password) and then reset conectionString in App.config and then restart the App.
This action has to take place just for the very first time the application runs on specific machine.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your database on one machine with fixed IP and store this IP in connection string in web.config, Then, use this connection string to access database in your application.

Create application in 3 tier architecture, which help you deploy your application in above stated environment.